How can I scale down the day number size to 0.5 and rotate them 90 degrees counter-clockwise to fit the Gantt chart within the text width?
How can I scale down the day number size to 0.5 (for example) and rotate each number 90 degrees counter-clockwise so that the Gantt chart fits within the text width?
CODE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{ganttchart}[
    y unit title=.6cm,
    y unit chart=.8cm,
    time slot format=isodate,
    title/.append style={shape=rectangle, fill=black!10},
    title height=1,
    bar/.append style={fill=green!90},
    bar height=.5,
    bar label font=\normalsize\color{black!50},
    bar incomplete/.append style={fill=green!40},
    time slot format/start date=2024-10-01
    ]{2024-10-01}{2024-11-30}
    \gantttitlecalendar{year, month=name, day} \\
    \ganttset{progress label text={},
        bar incomplete/.append style={fill=black!40},
        group/.append style={draw=black, fill=black!80},} % this suppresses percentage done labels
    \ganttgroup{Aim 1: Hardware Setup}{2024-10-05}{2024-11-10} \\
    \ganttbar[progress=42, name=rclone]{R cloning}{2024-10-10}{2024-10-15}
\end{ganttchart}

\end{document}

OUTPUT:


With

x unit=0.24cm for the width of node days
title label node/.append style={rotate=90}  and  title label font=\tiny
margin=1cm in geometry

EDIT: We can also use title label text =\scalebox{0.5}{\strut#1}
code
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\usepackage[showframe,margin=1cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{ganttchart}[
    x unit=0.24cm,%<-- added
    y unit title=.6cm,
    y unit chart=.8cm,
    time slot format=isodate,
    title/.append style={shape=rectangle, fill=black!10},
    title height=1,
    bar/.append style={fill=green!90},
    bar height=.5,
    bar label font=\normalsize\color{black!50},
    bar incomplete/.append style={fill=green!40},
    time slot format/start date=2024-10-01
    ]{2024-10-01}{2024-11-30}
    \gantttitlecalendar{year, month=name} \\
    \gantttitlecalendar[
        title label node/.append style={
            rotate=90},
        title label text =\scalebox{0.5}{\strut#1},%
        % title label font=\tiny,
        ]{day} \\
    \ganttset{progress label text={},
        bar incomplete/.append style={fill=black!40},
        group/.append style={draw=black, fill=black!80},} % this suppresses percentage done labels
    \ganttgroup{Aim 1: Hardware Setup}{2024-10-05}{2024-11-10} \\
    \ganttbar[progress=42, name=rclone]{R cloning}{2024-10-10}{2024-10-15}
\end{ganttchart}

\end{document}



thanks a lot pascal, can I use scalebox{0.5}{...} instead \tiny?

replace title label font=\tiny by title label text =\scalebox{0.5}{\strut#1} I edited the answer

vielen dank !!!
